# How to parse a JSON file with volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley, android-json

I am working on an online radio app demo. I need to get some data from the internet like the station's name and slogan, I watched some tutorials on how to use volley to parse a JSON file and get my data from the internet but I have tried different methods and nothing seems to be working, here is a simplified code

CODE

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        textView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);



        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest("https://api.myjson.com/bins/cd6dh", null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("1");
                            for (int i = 0; i <= jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject station = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String stationname = station.getString("motto");
                                textView.append(stationname);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("volley", "error");

                    }
                });

            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

JSON URL 
https://api.myjson.com/bins/cd6dh

When I run this code my text still remains the same

Comment: `i <= jsonArray.length()`  is going to throw an out of bounds exception when you index the array. Maybe that's why it's not working?

Comment: You also should not use numbers as object keys... Use the index of the array directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not a `JSONObject` instead it is a `JSONArray` so you would use the `JSONArrayRequest` from `Volley` and not `JSONObjectRequest` like you are using. You are probably getting an exception there which you are catching. After you get the `JSONArray` this line will give you your **station** for the first station

```
JSONObject station = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("1").getJSONObject(0);
```

and

```
station.getString("motto");
```

will give you the motto for the station.

This is because your data structure is very complicated. I would suggest making it better and easier to navigate

---

This is what your code snippet for request should look like

```
  JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest("https://api.myjson.com/bins/cd6dh",
      new Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
          try {
            JSONObject station1 = response.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("1").getJSONObject(0);
            String stationName = station1.getString("motto");
          } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      },
      new ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
          Log.e("volley", "error");
        }
      });
      requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Turns out that other than the wrong request, you never assigned a listener either. It was null as the second parameter of your request.

Comment: I Just tried the code and it worked out perfectly, I really appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

can u try this :-

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response+""); // string is the most general datatype
Log.d("MyApp",jsonArray+"");
```

at this place

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("1");
```

Here - `String stationname = station.getString("motto");`

it can be

```
int stringIndex              = (i+1); // your jsonarray element are one more than the index
String key                    = String.valueOf(stringIndex); // convert the incremented index to string
JSONArray index        = new JSONArray(station.getString(key));// get string from the jsonobject and convert it to jsonarray
JSONObject indexed  = index.getJSONObject(0); // get the first object from the json array
String stationname      = indexed.getString("motto"); // finally get the motto value
```

A note :- your json array is not good as you are indexing based on numbers it could have been directly json objects in the array...

I hope it helps u :)

Comment: hi, i copied and pasted your code and i got an error you can see it at [link](https://ibb.co/gFSQ2R)

Comment: @OpeyemiSanusi check my answer. That code should work for it

Comment: use this once...new JSONArray(station.getString(key)); i have edited